# Is this proof of impossibility of measure on $\mathscr{P}([0,1])$ valid?

Tags: measure-theory

**The statement.** There is no (countably additive) measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathscr{P}([0,1])$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$ and $\mu([0,1])=1$.
**Note:** I am not assuming the invariance with translation, nor that the measure of an interval is its length. However, I assume the axiom of choice.

**Proof.**
Let's suppose that there is such measure $\mu$.
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]:t\mapsto\mu([0,t])$. Function $f$ is non-decreasing. It is easy to prove that $f$ is continuous. Equivalently, we have that $f(t)=\mu([0,t])=\mu([0,t))=\mu((0,t])=\mu((0,t))$, so let's define a helping notation $f(a,b):=f(b)-f(a)$, for $0\le a\le b\le 1$, while it's clear that $f(a,b)=\mu([a,b])=\mu([a,b))=\mu((a,b])=\mu((a,b))$.
Let $I_t=f^{-1}(\{t\})$. By their definition, all $I_t$ must be pair-wise disjoint. By monotonicity and continuity (and bounds) of $f$, for each $0\le t\le 1$ we have that $I_t$ is either a point or a closed interval. Let $H$ be the familiy of these $I_t$ which are intervals (and not points). The union of intervals in $H$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, and with intervals $I_t$ being disjoint, the sum of Lebesgue measures (lengths) of these intervals in $H$ must be not greater than the length of $[0,1]$ which is finite.. Since every interval $I_t$ has a postive measure, there is at most $\aleph_0$ intervals in $H$. In other words, $H$ is countable.
Let $p:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]:t\mapsto \min(I_t)$. This function is well defined because all $I_t$ are closed sets. This function is an injection because all $I_t$ are disjoint. This allows us to define the pullback measure $\mu^*:\mathscr{P}([0,1])\rightarrow[0,+\infty):A\mapsto \mu(p(A))$. Now, I can't find a short way to show this, but it's not hard to deduce that $$p((a,b))=(p(a),p(b))\setminus\bigcup\{(\min I_t,\max I_t]|I_t\in H\land a<t<b\}.$$ Let's call this line $(1)$. This yields: $(p(a),p(b))\setminus\bigcup H\subseteq p((a,b))\subseteq(p(a),p(b))$. Let's call this line $(2)$. We have: $\mu(p((a,b)))=\mu^*((a,b))$ and $\mu((p(a),p(b)))=f(p(a),p(b))=f(p(b))-f(p(a))=b-a$. Back to our $I$-intervals, $\mu$-measure of any $I_t$ is $0$, which follows quickly from the definition and the fact that it is either a point or interval. Since $H$ is countable, the $\mu$-measure of the union of intervals in $H$ is also $0$. So we also have that $\mu\big(\bigcup H\big)=0$. This allows us to complete our transition from $p$ to $\mu$: $\mu((p(a),p(b))\setminus\bigcup H)=\mu((p(a),p(b)))-\mu\big(\bigcup H\big)=(b-a)-0=b-a$. We can finally deduce from $(2)$ that $b-a\le\mu^*((a,b))\le b-a$, i.e. $\mu^*((a,b))=b-a$.    This shows that $\mu^*$ extends Lebesgue's measure from Borel's $\sigma$-algebra to the power set of $[0,1]$, where it's a standard result that it can't exist. This finishes the proof. EDIT: I was referring to the Vitali's set argument, indeed.

The reason I am confused about this proof is that it's short, I can't find a hole after so many reviews, but in [this book](https://books.google.rs/books/about/Real_Analysis_and_Probability.html?id=7UuT7UZViN0C) there is a proof of this theorem but with an extra assumption that the continuum hypothesis is true and the proof isn't as short and simple. It is located in the appendix C.

Attempting to justify the "easy to prove" parts:

**1.** - That $f$ is continuous:
$f(t)=$$\mu([0,t])$$=$$\mu([0,t))$$=$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mu([t(1-\frac{1}{2^k}),t(1-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}})))$$=$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\mu([0,t(1-\frac{1}{2^n})))$$=$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}f(t(1-\frac{1}{2^n}))$. Since $f$ is monotone, this is enough to show that $f$ is continuous from left. Analogously it is proven that it is continuous from right.

Comment: You lost me with your first line: "Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]:t\mapsto\mu([0,t])$." What does this double colon mean?

Comment: This is the question of whether there is a real-valued measurable cardinal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable  So I (without reading it) I conclude there is an error

Comment: @Michael Sorry, Michael, I forgot to address your question. This question about double colon is just how I was taught to define functions in one like. after first colon I state the domain and the codomain, and after the second colon I define the mapping. Where $\mapsto$ is read as "is mapped to". About family $H$, I meant that $H$ is the _set of sets_. Concretely, the set of intervals. then $\cup H$ is the union across $H$, i.e. the union of all elements of $H$. Elements of $H$ are themselves sets so this makes sense.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I am aware of the theorem you meant to cite. It is the one I linked too. I only guess that that theorem assumes continuum hypothesis while mine assumes the axiom of choice. Maybe that is what differs them?

Comment: I got to the end and could not find a mistake. My residual comment is that $\mu^*$ needs to be shown to be a measure but I think it is due to disjointness property of the $p$ function. I had a few other notational difficulties like $f^{-1}(t)$ should be $f^{-1}(\{t\})$ and that line (*) should really be written as its own line, with parentheses to show where the subset signs should be parsed.  In the end this is also relying on the Vitali set argument due to its final statement (so the axiom of choice is used) but I do not think the continuum hypothesis is used.

Comment: @Michael, You're right, I am working on clarification, thank you

Comment: @donaastor : Wait a minute, I was assuming the "extension of Lebesgue measure" result is the same as the standard Vitali set argument, but perhaps it is not: The Vitali set argument requires translation invariance, but an extension of Lebesgue measure need not be translation invariant. So, what is the "standard result" that it cannot exist that you are referring to?  In other words, perhaps your proof (only) shows that your measure implies a (possibly non-translation invariant) extension of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Michael It looks like you answered my question... my proof is not valid!

Comment: @Michael Thank you for reviewing my work and finding an error!

Comment: Where does this break down if $\mu(A) = \mathcal{H}^d(A \cap \mathcal{C})$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set, $d$ is its Hausdorff dimension $\ln(2)/\ln(3)$, and $\mathcal{H}^d$ is the Hausdorff outer measure? (I think this means $p$ will be the Cantor function.)

Comment: @aschepler : Why should your measure be a measure on all subsets of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Michael Probably that's where it breaks then, at the very start. I'm learning things from this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer summarizes my comments above.

This proof starts with the assumption that there is a countably additive measure $\mu:2^{[0,1]}\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\mu(\{t\})=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. I believe all of its steps are correct, and it concludes that there is an extension of the Borel measure on $[0,1]$ to all subsets of $[0,1]$.

However, this extension **need not be translation invariant**. So it does not contradict the well known Vitali set argument (which uses the axiom of choice to show that such an extension that is translation invariant cannot exist). So the very last line of the proof seems incorrect, since I am not aware of any (basic) result that says a (possibly nontranslation invariant) extension of the Borel measure cannot exist. [There is a result in Billingsley that proves such a thing cannot exist, but it also assumes the continuum hypothesis (similar to the book linked in the question).]

Comment: Since no one can find a resource that proves or disproves my statement, is it perhaps an open problem? Namely if we substitute the continuum hypothesis with the axiom of choice in theorems we both linked?

Comment: Billingsley's "Probability and Measure" (end of chapter 3) uses both the axiom of choice and the continuum hypotheses. I believe the Dudley book also uses both (I think it implicitly uses the axiom of choice when it talks about well orderings). So the question would be whether or not the continuum hypotheses can be removed (while maintaining the axiom of choice).